# `rake db:schema:dump` creates schema with empty system tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, activerecord, tiny-tds

I am creating test and development databases that mirror the schema of an existing production database.  First, I create db/schema.rb by dumping the production schema:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:schema:dump
```

This creates a schema.rb which has an empty table for each system table:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 0) do

  create_table "MSreplication_objects", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
  end

  ...
```

These empty tables cause an error when I try to create the test and development databases:

```
$ rake db:reset
-- create_table("MSreplication_objects", {:id=>false, :force=>:cascade})
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: TinyTds::Error: Incorrect syntax near ')'.: CREATE TABLE [MSreplication_objects] ()
```

If, in schema.rb, I delete the definitions for the system tables, then the databases are created normally:

```
$ rake db:reset
-- create_table("Org", {:primary_key=>"org_id", :force=>:cascade})
   -> 0.0434s
   -> -1 rows
...
```

**How can I keep `rake db:schema:dump` from dumping the definitions for empty system tables that cannot be created?**

---

Versions:

- Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (x64)
- rails (4.2.1)
- activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (4.2.4)
- tiny_tds from github:

  - git://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds.git
  - Commit c4e59ba82c0cc55a5587cec1b7d5100d1b1ccaf4

Comment: Get a real database :) ?  This sounds like an adapter/DB specific issue.

Comment: Also its `rake db:schema:dump`

Comment: @papirtiger Thanks for the correction.  This is what happens when I type from memory instead of cutting and pasting.  And yes, I wish I could have a different database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is hope:

[ActiveRecord::SchemaDumper](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/edd11aa893485239d16b9bfb4eb4bcb41caeda56/activerecord/lib/active_record/schema_dumper.rb#L18) which does most of the heavy lifting supplies a singleton method for ignoring tables:

```
ActiveRecord::SchemaDumper.ignore_tables = ['MSreplication_objects', 'MSAnotherStupidSystemTable']
```

`activerecord-sqlserver-adapter` does not seem to supply its own rake task for dumping the schema (which it should) where this should have been done.

Comment: You might want to check out [databases.rake](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake#L48) if you decide to make your own rake task.

Comment: ignore_tables takes a regular expression, so `ActiveRecord::SchemaDumper.ignore_tables = [/^MS/]` works perfectly.  Thanks!